# Output field and button disappears when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

When the button is clicked, only the fist result is displayed but the button and the second result disappears. 
The following error is displayed "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null"
How can I avoid this?

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>


<script src="formBuilder.js"></script>

<label for="Volumenstrom">Volumenstrom: </label>
<input type="number" id="Volumenstrom" name="Volumenstrom">

<label for="Betriebsdruck">Betriebsdruck: </label>
<input type="number" id="Betriebsdruck" name="Betriebsdruck">

<label for="Betriebstemperatur">Betriebstemperatur: </label>
<input type="number" id="Betriebstemperatur" name="Betriebstemperatur">


<h1> Berechnung für Gase im Normzustand </h1>
<form>
<h2> Ergebnis der Berechnung </h2>

<label for="eqVolumenstrom">equiv. Wasservolumenstrom: </label>
<output name"eqVolumenstrom" id="eqVolumenstrom">

<label for="Druckverlust">Druckverlust: </label>
<output name="Druckverlust" id="Druckverlust">

<button onclick="wasservolumen()"; >Berechnen</button>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Java

```
function wasservolumen() {
     var volumen = parseInt(document.getElementById("Volumenstrom").value);
      var druck = parseInt(document.getElementById("Betriebsdruck").value);
      var temperatur = parseInt(document.getElementById("Betriebstemperatur").value);
      var wvolumen = volumen + druck + temperatur;
      var dverlust = druck * temperatur;
      console.log(volumen);
      console.log(druck);
      console.log(temperatur);
      console.log(wvolumen);
      console.log(dverlust);
      document.getElementById("eqVolumenstrom").value = wvolumen;
      document.getElementById("Druckverlust").value = dverlust;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the semi colon here

```
<button onclick="wasservolumen();">Berechnen</button>
```

also this html element the name attribute has no =

```
<output name"eqVolumenstrom" id="eqVolumenstrom"></output>
```

to

```
<output name="eqVolumenstrom" id="eqVolumenstrom"></output>
```

change the form method to post `<form method="post">`

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I corrected the code but it doesn´t solve the problem.

Comment: Ok lookingforward at your code again, the first two vars have this (document. Remove the (

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the HTML code

```
<label for="eqVolumenstrom">equiv. Wasservolumenstrom: </label>
<output name"eqVolumenstrom" id="eqVolumenstrom">

<label for="Druckverlust">Druckverlust: </label>
<output name="Druckverlust" id="Druckverlust">
```

to

```
<p>
<label for="eqVolumenstrom">equiv. Wasservolumenstrom: </label>
<output type="number" name="eqVolumenstrom" id="eqVolumenstrom">
</p>

<p>
<label for="Druckverlust">Druckverlust: </label>
<output type="number" name="Druckverlust" id="Druckverlust">
</p>
```

This brings the var dverlust up for a milisecond and the button does not disappeared. But after then the form is blank.